# Fix violation on Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self'

Tags: images, lightning-web-components

New to lightning Web Components and trying to follow a simple tutorial by adding an image to an lwc component. When I deploy it to the org, I get an error on the browser:

Refused to load the image  because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: blob:

Code:

```
<img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sfdc-demo/people/amy_taylor.jpg" alt="Profile photo">
```

I have explored other answers but I do not understand.
Solution 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484216/refused-to-load-the-image-blob-because-it-violates-the-following-content-s

Where to add

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="
      worker-src blob:; 
      child-src blob: gap:;
      img-src 'self' blob: data:;
      default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
```

to fix this?

Solution2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nf7eqg9WWPg&t=261s

I have no server.js in scripts folder

Newbie here, please be patient with your answers.

Answer (score 2):

login to salesforce -> Go to set up -> csp trusted site -> create new record -> add your url -> select the below content as needed and click save

Hopefully this will resolve your error.